# Spring Integration:Is there a way to aggregate from "all" messages in a channel?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to write a batch which reads website access log files(csv file)from a path every day and do some analysis using spring integration.

this is the simplified version of the input csv file.

```
srcIp1,t1,path1
srcIp2,t2,path2
srcIp1,t3,path2
srcIp1,t4,path1
```

The access number per source ip and path is to be calculated after some filtering logic.

I made a input channel whose payload is the parsed log line,and a filter is applied,and finally an aggregator to calculate the final result.
The problem is what should be the right group release stragety,the default release stragety(SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy) does not work.

Also any of other spring integraion out of box release

> strategies(ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy,
>   MessageCountReleaseStrategy, MethodInvokingReleaseStrategy,
>   SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy, TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy)

does not seem to fit my needs.

Or Spring integration assumed that a channel carries a message stream where there is no concept of "ending of message" and is not suitalbe for my problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom `ReleaseStrategy` if you have some way to tell when the group is complete. It is consulted each time a message is added to the group.

Or, you can use a `group-timeout` to release a partial group after some time when no messages arrived.

Comment: A channel views its payload as a message stream,The problem is that in the message per line context,there seemes no good way of writting the release stragety.So I changed to payload type to a single message of "all lines of all files" instead of one message per line.
Not a good idea,but could not think of a  better one.